# CIS hardened linux vs SELinux(Security Enhanced)

Tags: selinux, cis-framework

What are the differences between the CIS hardened linux and SELinux(security linux)? Also, all the public cloud service providers support CIS hardened linux. Does it mean SELinux has lost the battle? Or in terms of security, which flavor should I be choosing/using for a safety systems such as SIL4(SAFETY INTEGRITY LEVEL)?

Comment: AFAIK, CIS images use Selinux rather intensively, so the remark that Selinux may have lost the battle is bizarre.

Comment: In both AWS, Azure, I do see that RHEL, ubuntu linux images that are CIS certified using profile 1 and some are profile 2. Hence, I believe that is not the case.

Comment: https://securestack.com/base.html states: " We build our Base images with automation using the CIS benchmarks and build specifications.  We then add a second layer of custom hardening that dives deep into SELinux ..." so, that would suggest that they are using Selinux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are the differences between the CIS hardened linux and
> SELinux(security linux)?

The CIS guidelines cover a wide array of settings and configurations which improve security on a given system.  SELinux is a particular tool which can be used to apply mandatory access control to resources on a system.  As such, SELinux is one of the settings that CIS regulates:

```
1.6 Mandatory Access Control
  1.6.1.1 Ensure SELinux is not disabled in bootloader configuration (Scored)
  1.6.1.2 Ensure the SELinux state is enforcing (Scored)
  1.6.1.3 Ensure SELinux policy is configured (Scored)
```

> Also, all the public cloud service providers support CIS hardened
> linux. Does it mean SELinux has lost the battle?

No.  Firstly, since CIS and SELinux aim for different scopes of protection, they're not in competition, so there's no battle to be won or lost.  Secondly, you'll likely find SELinux installed and enforced on those images.

> Or in terms of security, which flavor should I be choosing/using for a
> safety systems

Harden according to the CIS guidelines, including SELinux by reference.  It's not an *either/or*, it's a *both*.